# Is Conan O'Brien bullying Jordan Schlansky?

Tags: production

Is there any evidence or interviews shining more light on the [incredibly confusing Jordan Schlansky situation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcK8HA5er-U)? For years Conan has been going on "remotes" with Jordan where they have conversations or go places, and the conceit of these remotes is basically always that Jordan has an unusual personality and Conan berates him mercilessly for it. I'm really curious what's going on behind the scenes.

- What official job does Jordan do for Conan?
- Does Conan actually directly employ Jordan, or is he employed by someone else who Conan also works for?
- Does he have a contract that prevents him from leaving Conan's employ?
- Has Jordan ever spoken about the nature of their relationship?
- Is he actually an actor that's playing this absurd character?
- Are there any other sources showing us what Jordan's really like away from Conan's antagonistic personality?

***What's going on?***

Comment: Can you provide a little more context what this question is about at all?

Comment: I'd be happy to, I just clarified that I'm talking about Conan O'Brien, is there anything else I could add?

Comment: What a "Jordan Schlansky" situation is in the first place, maybe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jordan is one of the "associate producers" at *Conan*, so yes, he is one of Conan's employees, and not an actor. However, I would suspect that a large portion of that on-screen character is a bit worked up between the two.

His "normal" job duties, as a [producer](http://www.producersguild.org/?page=faq), would be things like booking guests, ensuring that skits were properly set up, making sure graphics are put together. The specific work he did would be whatever the producer delegated to him.

If he genuinely felt bullied or uncomfortable with the working relationship, he would have any number of options (up to and including a lawsuit, depending on the severity of the harassment). The fact that he continues to allow himself to be on-camera and cooperates in the sketches should be all the "proof" you need to rest assured that he's in on the joke.

You can see Jordan discuss his job duties and Conan's bits on his [Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/1ajju2/i_am_jordan_schlansky_associate_producer_of_conan/).

Comment: Yeah his continued cooperation is what I find most confusing haha, but thanks for pointing out that AMA!

Comment: Craig Ferguson spent almost a year calling his producer a racist, every day on camera. He was obviously in on the joke, as Jordan is.

Comment: [Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Js6ephZRpME) where Jordan is *literally* participating in a sketch, and the focus isn't on him. He has lines and everything!